# Nested for-Loop in Jinja for Flask web

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, nested-loops

I'm looking to make a simple social networking web app. In the feed page I should print all the posts including the names of users who uploaded it plus the feedback of each post.

I'm facing a problem with showing the Jinja nested-loop since I don't know a good background about html.

This's my html file where I have 3 nested loops for username, feedback and the post. The problem that it just prints the first result of user and feedback and ignoring the rest. I need to show the results for all posts like this "user-feedback-post".

```
    {% for item1 in user %}
            {% for item2 in feed %}
                {% for item3 in image %}
        {{ item1 }} {% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}<br>
                 {{ item2 }} {% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}<br>
                    <img src="/static/images/{{ item3 }}" width="180" height="180"><br>  {% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}<br><br>

    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

file.py where I return the functions...

```
return render_template("home.html", feed=post_feed(), image=post_image(), user=post_user())
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nested loop like this, you need to make reference to the outer objects in the inner `for` statements.

Something like:

```
    {% for item1 in user %}
        {% for item2 in item1.feed %}
            {% for item3 in item2.image %}
```

The details will depend on how the data is structured coming in.

As a suggestion, probably also rename the variables to be more meaningful?

```
    {% for user in users %}
        {% for feed_item in user.feed %}
            {% for image in feed_item.images %}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! and is my printing correct? because I did it but nothing shows up on the page

Comment: You don't appear to be passing in a nested data structure into the `render_template`; rather, you're passing in three individual items. You'll need to make sure that the data structure you pass in and the data structure you use in the template match.